# Prove the following interpolation inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, interpolation-theory

> Let $f \in L^1(\mathbf R^N \times \mathbf R^N) \cap L^p(\mathbf R^N \times \mathbf R^N)$. Let $\rho(x) = \int_{\mathbf R^N} f(x,v) dv$. Prove that
> \begin{equation}
> \|\rho\|_{L^q(\mathbf R^N)} \le C \|f|v|^2\|_{L^1(\mathbf R^N \times \mathbf R^N)}^\theta \|f\|_{L^p(\mathbf R^N \times \mathbf R^N)}^{1-\theta}
> \end{equation}
> where $C$ is some positive constant, $1\le p \le\infty$, $q = \frac{N(p-1)+2p}{N(p-1)+2}$, $\theta = \frac{1}{q}\frac{p-q}{p-1}$.

This inequality appears in [this paper at equation (35)](http://www.seminariomatematico.polito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/46-3/259.pdf) without any proof. I have no idea to   prove it. Can anyone give some hints? TIA...

---

Note: From the definition of $q$ and $\theta$, we have
$$\frac{1}{q-1}-\frac{1}{p-1} = \frac{N}{2},$$
$$\theta + \frac{1-\theta}{p} = \frac{1}{q}.$$

Comment: What do you mean with $f|v|^2$ here?
Have you tried to use any standard interpolation inequalities?

Comment: I haven't worked out the details but looks like Riesz-Thorin Interpolation should be useful.

Comment: @supinf Yes I tried the interpolation. But I don't know how the term $f|v|^2$ comes out.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho But how the term $f|v|^2$ comes out? If I use the interpolation, should there be $f$ in place of $f|v|^2$? Thank you.